# How to call `showWaitScreenWithNoClose` while calling `AJAXRefreshView`?

Tags: 2013, javascript, jsom

I am using the code snippet from this [link](https://www.eliostruyf.com/ajax-refresh-item-rows-in-sharepoint-2013-view/) to refresh the view. It works perfectly fine.

```
  // Set Ajax refresh context
  var evtAjax = {
    currentCtx: ctx,
    csrAjaxRefresh: true
  };
  // Initiate Ajax Refresh on the list
  AJAXRefreshView(evtAjax, SP.UI.DialogResult.OK);
```

What I am looking for is a way to call [`showWaitScreenWithNoClose`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff408140(v=office.14).aspx) brefore and after the function `AJAXRefreshView` refreshes the view so that user has some visual indication that some refresh is happening. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the code used to refresh, you'll notice it uses the `CLVPOnReadyStateChangeCallback` function and that funtion has a check for a callback function:

```
    if (typeof clvp.ctx.onDataRefreshCompleted == "function") {
        callback = clvp.ctx.onDataRefreshCompleted;
        clvp.ctx.onDataRefreshCompleted = null
    }
```

You can then do it like this:

```
ctx.onDataRefreshCompleted = function() {
    waitDialog.close(); 
}

var waitDialog =  SP.UI.ModalDialog.showWaitScreenWithNoClose(SP.Res.dialogLoading15);

var evtAjax = {
    currentCtx: ctx,
    csrAjaxRefresh: true
  };

AJAXRefreshView(evtAjax, SP.UI.DialogResult.OK);
```

If you have multiple webparts you could use the `g_ctxDict` to get the right "ctx" based on different values, like the Title:

```
AJAXRefreshView({
    currentCtx: (function(ctx) { 
        var waitDialog =  SP.UI.ModalDialog.showWaitScreenWithNoClose(SP.Res.dialogLoading15);
        ctx.onDataRefreshCompleted = function() {
            waitDialog.close(); 
        }       
        return ctx;

    })(g_ctxDict[Object.keys(g_ctxDict).filter(function(c) { return g_ctxDict[c].ListTitle === "Tasks" })]),
    csrAjaxRefresh: true
  }, SP.UI.DialogResult.OK);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use [setTimeout](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) method to display the processing.

```
// Set Ajax refresh context
  var evtAjax = {
    currentCtx: ctx,
    csrAjaxRefresh: true
  };
  // Initiate Ajax Refresh on the list
  setTimeout(showWaitScreenWithNoClose(), 3000);
  AJAXRefreshView(evtAjax, SP.UI.DialogResult.OK);
  setTimeout(showWaitScreenWithNoClose(), 3000);
```

I know it's not a good solution but It will work.

Answer (score -1):

To Show 'showWaitScreenWithNoClose' Dialog:

```
var waitDialog =  SP.UI.ModalDialog.showWaitScreenWithNoClose(SP.Res.dialogLoading15);
```

To Hide or Remove 'showWaitScreenWithNoClose' Dialog:

```
window.parent.waitDialog.close();
```

Comment: I know how to call the `showWaitScreenWithNoClose` method. But how do I know that the view is refreshed after call to `AJAXRefreshView` which is an asynchronous event.